# Time average of set of trials in Julia?

Tags: loops, for-loop, testing, julia, benchmarking

In Julia, I have a function that times each iteration of a for loop using **@elapsed** macro, shown below. Instead of timing each iteration, I would like to perform each "kth" iteration **100 times**, and record the **average of those 100 trials** as the "time" of each iteration, stored in **time_vector** array. Is there any way to modify this function to accomplish this?

```
 function timeloop2(k)
    time_vector = zeros(k)
    for x = 1:k
         #for each iteration k, do 100 trials and compute "average" of 100 trials?
         #how to store each average of 100 trials in time_vector?
         t = @elapsed begin    
             L₁=rand(10,k)                
             L₂=rand(k,10)
             L₁*L₂
         end 
         time_vector[x] = t
     end 
     time_vector  
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this should work for this specific case

```
function timeloop2(k)
    time_vector = zeros(k)
    for x = 1:k
         t = @elapsed for j in 1:100
             L₁=rand(10,k)                
             L₂=rand(k,10)
             L₁*L₂
         end
         time_vector[x] = t/100
     end 
     time_vector  
  end
```

However, perhaps you would be interested in using [BenchmarkTools](https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/) for benchmarking in general.

Answer (score 0):

For accurate results, it's most advisable to use `@benchmark` from [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/#BenchmarkTools). The output of `@benchmark` will contain a lot of information like `allocs`, `gctimes`, `memory`, `params`, `times`; what you're interested in here is average of the `times` vector. So, calculating `mean(t.times)` and dividing by `10^9` will give the correct result in seconds.

Note that `@benchmark` will automatically run the code for as many times as is required for accurate timing. But note also that we should interpolate variables like `$k` to avoid dealing with global variables that lead to inaccurate results.

```
using BenchmarkTools

function timeloop2(k)
    time_vector = zeros(k)
    for x = 1:k
         t = @benchmark begin    
             L₁ = rand(10, $k)                
             L₂ = rand($k, 10)
             L₁ * L₂
         end 
         time_vector[x] = mean(t.times)/10^9
     end 
     time_vector  
end
```

Example:

```
timeloop2(9)
9-element Vector{Float64}:
 7.992059027777779e-7
 8.008377931034483e-7
 8.042304827586206e-7
 7.996186206896552e-7
 8.017322068965517e-7
 7.996148275862069e-7
 7.990756551724139e-7
 8.239104999999999e-7
 8.269181679389314e-7
```